# HannWindow implementation and discretization speed

Tags: functions, performance-tuning

I would like to discretize a series of `HannWindow`s, but two issues arise. First, my manual implementation of `HannWindow` seems to discretize faster than the built-in function. Second, the discretization in both cases is slow.

I begin by defining variables which give the Hann windows each different widths and locations:

```
{hmax, sbase, mcoeff, mmax, kmax, hf} = {30, 468, 2, 237, 10, 2};
{hbc, hb, hwf} = {2, 60, 100};
len = 2401;

Do[widthbuffer[n] = hbc*n + hb;
 hw[n] = ((8*n + hwf)/2 + widthbuffer[n]), {n, 1, hmax}]
```

Then I construct a set of functions, indexed by `k` and `m`, each of which is a series of Hann windows. Using the built-in function:

```
Do[sep = sbase + mcoeff*m;
 Do[hc[n] = 222 + (n - 1)*sep + (-1 + 2 k/kmax)*706/10, {n, hf,hmax}];
  hannM[k][m] = Sum[HannWindow[(t - hc[n])/(2 hw[n])], {n, hf, hmax}], 
 {k, 0,kmax}, {m, 1, mmax}]

(* 1.52106s *)
```

If I manually implement the `HannWindow`, the timing is slightly different:

```
Do[sep = (sbase + mcoeff*m); 
 Do[hc[n] = 222 + (n - 1)*sep + (-1 + (2*k/kmax))*(706/10); 
  harg[n] = (t - hc[n])/(2 hw[n]); hl[n] = hc[n] - hw[n]; 
  hr[n] = hc[n] + hw[n];
  hann[n] = 
  Piecewise[{{0.5 + 0.5*Cos[2 Pi*harg[n]], 
  hl[n] <= t <= hr[n]}}], {n, hf, hmax}];
 hannc[k][m] = Sum[hann[n], {n, hf, hmax}], {m, 1, mmax}, {k, 0,kmax}]

(* 1.77596s *)
```

Now, discretizing for `k=0` and `m=1`, for example, shows very different timings. Using the built-in `HannWindow`:

```
hMT = Table[hannM[0][1], {t, len}];

(* 0.441911s *)
```

Using my manual implementation:

```
hcT = Table[hannc[0][1], {t, len}];

(* 0.056057s *)
```

What accounts for the difference in speed between these two methods, and is there a way to speed up the discretization, which for both cases seems to be slow?

Comment: `hannc[0][1]` is a function defined by `Piecewise`. That can easily be compiled by `Table` while `HannWindow` is probably not compilable.

Comment: In the documentation it looks like `HannWindow` is defined `Piecewise`. I suppose there must be an additional feature which is slowing it down.

Comment: Did you check how fast it is when you apply `FunctionExpand` to `HannWindow`?

Comment: @Mathe172 Thanks for the suggestion. `FunctionExpand` reduces the discretization time by a factor of about 3.7, so that is an improvement over simply applying `HannWindow`. The manual method is still 2 times faster than this, however.